# Oracle: Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write Oracle dynamic SQL to do row count, below is my approach, please help me complete.

This is my select to generate the individual count statements:

```
select 'select count(*) from '||table_name||';'
from dba_tables
where owner = 'URR';
```

This is how I started:

```
declare
  l_owner varchar2(30) := 'URR';
  l_table_name varchar2(30);
  l_columns varchar2(32000);
  l_sql varchar2(32000);
begin
```

Comment: Read about [execute immediate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example that looks at tables in your own schema:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    c number;
begin
    for r in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name
            into c;
        dbms_output.put_line(r.table_name ||': '|| c);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

To look at someone else's tables you'll need to use `dba_tables` as you started to try, or more likely `all_tables` as that should exclude tables you can't count from, but you'll also need to specify the owner in the `count` statement.

Normally you'd want to use bind variables to avoid SQL injection, but you have to specify object names with concatenation like this.

Something else to look out for is a mistake you had in your query, but which Egor has now removed from the question. The dynamic SQL string you execute should not be terminated by a semicolon (`;`).