# Oracle sql output use as tablename in FROM statement

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this statement;

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'DUMPDATE'
```

it returns the table names that contain columns names "dumpdate";

```
TABLE1
TABLE2
etc
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT DUMPDATE 
FROM   TABLE1
```

etc etc.
Is there a way to do this in one single SQL query?

Comment: select * from (select table_name from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'DUMPDATE'); try thid

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL for this; essentially [the same as this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16320892/266304), except you want `dumpdate` instead of `count(*)` in the dynamic query. But it isn't clear what you want to do with the results; do you just want to display them, or make them available as a result set?

Comment: Yup that example does the job! Thanks a lot.